# Meteor subscribe to same collection 2 different publish functions just one works at given time

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor collection

`channels = new Meteor.Collection('channels');` at `collections` folder

and 2 publish functions `channelsNames` is used in the sidebar navigation to show available channels and when I go to channel settings I also use `channelSettings` to get the settings for this specific channel. By iron-router

```
//Publish specfic channel settings
Meteor.publish("channelSettings", function(channel){
  check(channel, String);
  return channels.find({userId: this.userId, 'channels.name': channel}, {fields: {'channels.$': 1}} );
});

//Publish all connected channels names
Meteor.publish("channelsNames", function() {
  return channels.find({userId: this.userId, 'channels.name': {$exists: true}}, {fields: {'channels.name': 1}});
});
```

The problem is over the client you can't subscribe to both of them only the first subscription will be seen on the client collection when I do in console `channels.findOne` I can verify I don't see `channelsname` if `channelsSettings` is subscribed first and the opposite is also true

```
Meteor.subscribe('channelSettings', 'ebay');
Meteor.subscribe('channelsNames');
```

the collection looks like this

```
{
 _id:  2,
 userId: 123,
 channels: [ 
  {name: "channel1", inventorySync: false, inventoryMaxqty: 0, inventoryMinQty: 0},
  {name: "channel2", inventorySync: false, inventoryMaxqty: 0, inventoryMinQty: 0}
 ]
}
```

Is this an expected behavior? I thought meteor should combine both data to one collection. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm quite certain that's expected behavior (at the moment). You're not the first one finding this strange.

Comment: This is the expected behavior because the merge box currently only works on top level fields. See [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/998) and [this post](https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-mergebox.html) for more details.

Comment: Yeah sucks! I have to workaround this, I wish it was supported already.